# Adding a zope folder with python

Tags: python, zope

For a webbased application me and my team have been working with the Zope 2 framework (http://docs.zope.org/zope2/). It provides a nice web interface with which you can create, edit and delete file and folder objects. Let's say I have a root folder '/', using the interface I can add a new folder without any problems. Now I want to manage the same with a python script, but I have not been able to get this to work.

A few of the approaches I have tried in Zope (in a script that runs from '/'):

```
context.manage_addFolder( id='name', title='' )
container.manage_addFolder( id='name', title='' )
container.manage_addProduct['OFSP'].manage_addFolder( id='name', title='' )
container.restrictedTraverse( '/' ).manage_addFolder( id='name', title='' )
container.restrictedTraverse( '/' ).manage_addProduct['OFSP'].manage_addFolder( id='name', title='' )
```

However, none of these creates a folder. The strange thing is that the script is executed fine in that no errors are thrown, but it produces no folder. At first I thought this might be a permission thing, but the strange behaviour persisted even when I enabled all permissions for every user in Zope.

Wat am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

All this works for me when executed on a Zope 2.13.x with manager role as a python script inside the Zope UI:

```
context.manage_addFolder('justatest')
container.manage_addFolder('justatest2')
```

The easiest way to allow normal users the creation of folders is to assign a proxy role to the python script that is creating the folder. The manager role is convenient, but you should prepare a role with less permissions for this task.